# Can I retrieve GPS location in App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

Is there a way to retrieve GPS location from a device in an App Maker app?

I'm trying to create a "checkin" app for my users. I want to retrieve their GPS location (lattitude, longitude) when they submit their "checkin".

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can, on a Chrome browser, see https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/user-location/ for all the details.

```
if (navigator.geolocation){
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
    console.log(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  });
}
```

The user must consent to disclosing their location.